# Cayley-Hamilton Theorem

Tags: matrices, ring-theory

I am trying to prove that all strictly upper triangular $n \times n$ matrices $A$, are nilpotent such that $A^n=0$.

I am having trouble proving:

> $A$'s eigenvalues are all zero implies that $A^n=0$.

I have the hint to use Cayley-Hamilton, but I'm unsure how to use Cayley-Hamilton to do so.  Is there some part of Cayley-Hamilton that says that $A^n=$ characteristic polynomial of $A$?

Comment: Perhaps you can prove that, if, in $A,$ the only nonzero coefficients allowed are $a_{ij}$ with $i < j,$ then for $A^2$ only $i+1 <j,$ also for $A^3$ only $i+2 < j,$ and so on. Try it for some 2 by 2 matrices and some 3 by 3.

Answer (score 4):

You are on the right track. Let's start from the beginning. We wish to prove:

If $A$ is an $n\times n$ strictly upper triangular matrix, $A^n=0$.

We can prove this statement by finding $A$'s characteristic polynomial. To do this, we must look at $A$'s matrix:

$$A=
\begin{bmatrix} 0        &          & \huge{\star} \\
                         & \ddots   &              \\
                \huge{0} &          &  0           \\ \end{bmatrix}$$

Let's denote $\text{char poly}_x\{A\}$ as $f(x)$.

$$\Rightarrow f(x) = \text{det }\{x\cdot I-A\} = \left|
\begin{bmatrix} x        &          &   \\
                         & \ddots   &   \\
                         &          & x \\ \end{bmatrix}-
\begin{bmatrix} 0        &          & \huge{\star} \\
                         & \ddots   &              \\
                \huge{0} &          &  0           \\ \end{bmatrix}\right|$$

$$\dots= \left|
\begin{bmatrix} x        &          & -\huge{\star} \\
                         & \ddots   &               \\
                \huge{0} &          &  x            \\ \end{bmatrix}\right|$$

The determinant of an upper triangular matrix is the product of it's diagonals (proofs of this can be found elsewhere on this website) so $f(x)=x^n$.

Recall that the Cayley-Hamilton theorem says that $f(A)=0$.

Now $A^n=0.$

Answer (score 3):

If $A$ has eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n$, what is the characteristic polynomial of $A$?

If $\lambda_1 = \cdots = \lambda_n = 0$, what is the characteristic polynomial of $A$?

Comment: the characteristic polynomial would be 0

Comment: so p(lambda)=lambda^n (because all the eigenvalues are the same since the diagonal of a strictly upper triangular matrix is all 0s), and p(lambda)=lambda^n=0, so p(A)=A^n=0?

Comment: Remember that the definition of a characteristic polynomial is: $\text{char poly } A = \text{det } x\cdot I - A$

Comment: So in general, given the eigenvalues of $A$ as above (including multiplicity), the characteristic polynomial is $$p_A(\lambda) = (\lambda-\lambda_1)\cdots (\lambda - \lambda_n)$$ So, indeed, if $A$ has only $0$ as an eigenvalue $n$ times, then the characteristic polynomial of $A$ will be $(\lambda-0)^n = \lambda^n$.  Thus, $A^n = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

I propose a more elementary solution.

Suppose that $A=(C_1|C_2|C_3|\cdots |C_n)$ where $C_1=0$, $C_2=(c_{12},0,0,\ldots)$, $C_3=(c_{13},c_{23},\cdots)$, &c. Consider now $A$ as a map $T:K^n\to K^n$ with $x\mapsto Ax$. Observe that if $e_i$ is the $i$-th canonical vector then $Ae_1=0$ and for $i>1$, $Ae_i=C_i\subseteq\langle e_{1},\ldots,e_{i-1}\rangle$. Prove then by induction that $A^ie_i=0$ for every $i$. In particular, $A^ne_i=0$ for every $i$, so $A^n=0$.

*Hint* To see what's going on, note that $A^2e_i=AAe_i\subseteq \langle Ae_1,\ldots,Ae_{i-1}\rangle=\langle 0,Ae_2,\ldots,Ae_{i-1}\rangle$. But  we have $Ae_2\in \langle e_1\rangle$, $Ae_3\in \langle e_1,e_2\rangle,\cdots, Ae_{i-1}\in \langle e_1,\ldots,e_{i-2}\rangle $ so that $A^2e_i\in \langle e_1,\ldots,e_{i-2}\rangle$. Since $Ae_2\in \langle e_1\rangle$, we get $A^2e_2=0$, for $Ae_1=0$. For $i>2$ then  $A^2e_i\in \langle e_1,\ldots,e_{i-2}\rangle$. If $i=3$, we get $A^2e_3\in \langle e_1\rangle$, so $A^3e_3=0$, and so on.